# Rx ObserveOn() in ASP .NET Core Razor pages

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, system.reactive

There isn’t a SynchronizationContext in ASP.NET Core, as [explained here by Stephen Cleary](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2017/03/aspnetcore-synchronization-context.html). When using Reactive eXtensions, how can you pass to `ObserveOn()` the current synchronisation context of Razor pages?

```
using var subscription = theObservable
    .SubscribeOn(ThreadPoolScheduler.Instance)
    .ObserveOn(SynchronizationContext.Current) // <-- This is null???
    .Subscribe(x => DoSomethingWith(x));
```

Comment: Am I right that you're trying to react on **server** for a some event from **client**? If ao, then you don't need RX for that

Comment: @VMAtm, In this case, all happen on controller. Suppose all the server side things are done, and we have a bunch of data on controller. This observable is supposed to use threading to speed up things on controller and then finally we want results to be observed on current synchronisation context of the controller.

Comment: What do you mean by `observed`? It's a website, nothing is run on server without client request. If you need some of a background work, you need to implement some kind of daemon or windows service. Right now you're trying to solve this task on WEB server with instruments for WINDOWS server. It's just wouldn't work

Comment: Are you trying to ensure you run on a single thread or are you specifically wanting to run on the current thread?

Comment: @Enigmativity, I want to take advantage of thread-pool threads and run the observable there, but when its job is completed then I want to have the results available and use them on the main thread.

Comment: @CloudWindMoonSun - Does `SynchronizationContext.SetSynchronizationContext(new SynchronizationContext());` help?

Comment: @Enigmativity no it didn't help. I tried it.